# how to made next code slider for new table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slideshow

hiii everyone,

i want to make a slider for exercise1 and exercise2 in same html page if i select next then it will appear next exrcise after complete exercise as same as image slider it will not show two exrsice at same time only one will be display at a time and should wiork as slider for next exrecise please help me to develope this

my jsfiddle is :jsfiddle.net/hirenwebdp/Ky8fP/7/

In my jsfiddle you can see that there is two exercise in one html page but it no have slider both are appearing on same so i want to develope slider for exercises 1 and 2 
please help me

Comment: Is the answer not what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can use bxslider for this purpose. It's not just an image slider but also a content slider as well.

Here check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2HLX/)

Note that I have not implemented any validation. Like go to next slide only on completion of the first exercise etc. Hope you can achieve it on your own.

Include the bxslider js and css file and the plugin like this for eg.

```
$('.slider').bxSlider({
  mode: 'horizontal',
  auto: false
});
```

If you don't want infiniteLoop, you can set it to false too.

```
 $('.slider').bxSlider({
  mode: 'horizontal',
  auto: false,
  infiniteLoop:false
  });
```